# TypeError: to_append should be a Series or list/tuple of Series, got DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, append, concatenation

Code was working earlier then just stopped.

I don't understand why, if somebody could help me with shedding some light on the subject that would be awesome.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re
import pandas as pd
import requests


locations = ['las-vegas-nv','denver-co']
for location in locations:
    headers = {
        'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36'
    }



    url = f'https://www.apartments.com/{location}/1-bedrooms/'
    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = bs(page.text, 'lxml')
    table = soup.find("table", class_="rentTrendGrid")
    rows = []

    for tr in table.find_all('tr'):
        rows.append([td.text for td in tr.find_all(['th', 'td'])])

#header_row = rows[0]
    rows = list(zip(*rows[0:])) # tranpose the table
    df = pd.DataFrame(rows[1:], columns=rows[0])
    df['City'] = location
    dfs.append(df)
    df = pd.concat(dfs).reset_index(drop = True)
print(df)
```

Comment: what is `dfs`? I don't see it defined anywhere.

Comment: It me just messing around with the code...I know that it isn't defined but when the dfs is equal to df it still throws the same error

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just needed to take the last portion out of the for loop

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re
import pandas as pd
import requests


locations = ['las-vegas-nv','denver-co', 'lehi-ut']

dfs = []
for location in locations:
    headers = {
        'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36'
    }



    url = f'https://www.apartments.com/{location}/1-bedrooms/'
    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = bs(page.text, 'lxml')
    table = soup.find("table", class_="rentTrendGrid")
    rows = []

    for tr in table.find_all('tr'):
        rows.append([td.text for td in tr.find_all(['th', 'td'])])

#header_row = rows[0]
    rows = list(zip(*rows[0:])) # tranpose the table
    df = pd.DataFrame(rows[1:], columns=rows[0])
    df['City'] = location
    dfs.append(df)
df = pd.concat(dfs).reset_index(drop = True)
print(df)
```